# Riddle Poem: Even when I'm alone, you may still see two

Tags: riddle

Who or what is this poem referring to?

> Don't confuse me with a line
>   A line may contain me
>   And I may contain a line
>   But that's not my identity
>
> I have one best friend
>   Though I don't often appear
>   When I do show up
>   He's almost always near
>
> I can be round and tall
>   And may touch facial hair
>   But even when I'm alone
>   You may still see two there
>
> Find me in ancient places
>   I am worth quite a lot
>   I can bring about the end
>   But I'm rarely in that spot

Comment: The first two verses make me think of a point in projective geometry...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Is it

> the letter "q"?

Don't confuse me with a line
A line may contain me

> Don't confuse "q" with "queue", another word for "line". Also, a line of text may contain an "q"

And I may contain a line
But that's not my identity

> "q" contains a line, but it's more than just a line.

I have one best friend
Though I don't often appear

> The letter "u", but "q" is not frequently used

When I do show up
He's almost always near

> "q" and "u" come together, usually

I can be round and tall
And may touch facial hair

> Uppercase "Q" is round and tall. The lowercase "q" has a descender! Descenders in letters reach downward toward the "beard line" in typography.

But even when I'm alone
You may still see two there

> An upper-case cursive "Q" looks a lot like the numeral "2"!

Find me in ancient places
I am worth quite a lot

> "Q" is found in "[quasars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar)", which are ancient, else we couldn't see them. Also, the Greeks only used the letter "Q" for the number 90, [but the Etruscans and Romans kept it for "Q"](http://webspace.ship.edu/cgboer/alphabet.html). Also, [it originated as the Phoenician symbol qop](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Q.aspx). "Q" is worth quite a lot in the game of Scrabble.

I can bring about the end
But I'm rarely in that spot

> Pressing "q" to end a program (old-school). Also, very few words end with the letter "q".

Comment: In which case I am surprised there is no reference to a queue being another name for a pigtail, or q denoting the number of farthings in old English coinage, or being a band of parchment attached to documents with seals at the end, or the forked (doubled) tail of heraldic beasts or a barrel of wine (Is this what is round and tall?). Q is often an abbreviation for "quit" to bring about the end, or "quarto" expensive early editions of Shakespearean plays. Cue is the conclusing word of a speech in a play. ("Cue entrance...")

Comment: Leo Goodstadt got the "bring about the end" clue - sometimes you can press `q` to end a computer program.

Comment: I was assuming "ancient places" was referring to "antiques" - valuable in their own right, but you're more likely correct I think

Comment: So many comments were erased. :(  The "ancient places" clue was referring to the word "quasars", although a few other explanations worked too.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That is an ugly edit, IMO, with some of JLee's comments now interspersed among the poem lines.  Also, the top 2 answers to that [meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/spoiler-markup) disagree with the meta post and have a combined score of 10, so that meta post cannot be regarded as community policy.

Comment: The poem lines should indeed ideally use quote markup, @pacoverflow, but that screws up the spoiler segments (another problem, like the one you posted about, with its rendering). I didn't refer to the Meta post you've linked.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Aha! I found a solution to the run-together blocks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144833/

Answer (score 8):

You're a

> Rainbow

Don't confuse me with a line

> Don't worry, you're a "bow"

A line may contain me

> Light rays travel on a straight line, but [if pointed on a prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Side_of_the_Moon), a rainbow is revealed

And I may contain a line

> [Rainbow colors](https://www.google.it/search?q=rainbow%20colors&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=-XNTVfD_DureywOq3oCoBQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) are always represented as straight lines. E.g. the [peace flag](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScAL6Vg43sETiFlsYAbdChblnDECg_GGXNSgBcdHJkojDk-D5w) is composed by lines of different colors. Our parents (and sadly also me) [know it best](https://connellydale.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/color-bars_large.jpg).

But that's not my identity

> The most famous rainbow is the one created by rain.

I have one best friend

> Sun

Though I don't often appear

> When it rains, not always a rainbow appears

When I do show up
He's almost always near

> Only when there is sun and rain a rainbow can occur

I can be round and tall

> [Round](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izeP4.jpg) and in the sky

And may touch facial hair

> [YEAH!](http://www.yorkpress.co.uk/resources/images/1700456/) (Really no clue here...)

But even when I'm alone
You may still see two there

> [Double rainbow!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQSNhk5ICTI) (actually is only one)

Find me in ancient places

> There are a lot of references to rainbows in [ancient mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbows_in_mythology)

I am worth quite a lot

> Mmmh, I think this one is a [hoax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pot_of_Gold).

I can bring about the end
But I'm rarely in that spot

> Have you ever tried to [chase the rainbow](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/chase+rainbows)? Even if an observer sees another observer who seems "under" or "at the end of" a rainbow, the second observer will see a different rainbow—farther off—at the same angle as seen by the first observer.

Comment: Clever answer! As for the "facial hair", how about the bearded iris flower, iris being Greek for rainbow?

Comment: the sun is not necessary for a rainbow.  just light.

Answer (score 4):

I thought of:

> A colon (:)

---

Don't confuse me with a line
A line may contain me

> A line of text may have a colon

And I may contain a line
But that's not my identity

> Usually in play scripts, a character name is followed by a colon then a line.
>  It also may be that when quoting pieces, you may do:
>            "A colon followed by a quote like I did right now" - Me 2015

I have one best friend
Though I don't often appear
When I do show up
He's almost always near

> The best friend would be a semi-colon (;), and in lists, if some elements have commas in them, you use a semi-colon to delimit. Some examples: Me, myself and I; Red, green and blue; and fish and chips.

I can be round and tall
And may touch facial hair

> I'm not sure about this one. The round may imply that the dots in a colon are round

But even when I'm alone
You may still see two there

> The dots in the colon can look like 2 separate dots

Find me in ancient places
I am worth quite a lot

> Not sure about this one.

I can bring about the end
But I'm rarely in that spot

> Sometimes a colon can end a sentence, but very rarely is it said to be two separate sentences (Rather one larger one)

Comment: +1, not a bad try.  But I wouldn't say that a colon is almost always near a semicolon.

Comment: consider :) or :{) for the clue you're not sure about

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> brackets: (), [] ? :)

---

> Brackets may contain a line and they also may be contained in one. 
>
>  There are always two of them (a friend)
>  
>  They can be round () and tall []
>  
>  An may touch facial hair :-{ :-)
>  
>  Parentheses (brackets are included in this group) is an Ancient Greek word.
>  
>  Middle French braguette - bragget (codpiece armor, 16th century). Sure it was a worthy thing)))

Right direction?